# parent class member in subclass using templates, without `this`

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I have the following hierarchy:

```
// the template of the class isn't important for
// the question, I'm using an enum in the real code
enum class State : int { S0, S1 /*... etc */ };

template<State S>
class Base {
public:
    Base(const Vector3f &position) : mPosition(position) {}
protected:
    Vector3f mPosition;
};

template<State S>
class Derived : public Base<S> {
public:
    Derived(const Vector3f &position) : Base<S>(position) {
        // vvvvvvvvv ERROR
        if(mPosition.norm() > 2.0f) { /* do stuff */ }
};
```

I am aware that I can use `this->mPosition` as well as `Base<S>::mPosition`, but I do not understand why.  If templates were not involved, it would compile.

I believe this is because at compile time there is no proof that all possible `Base<State S>` specializations (if they exist) will have an `mPosition`.  Is this correct?

In my particular scenario, I can guarantee that every version of `Base` and `Derived` will be compiled and that they will all also have `mPosition`.  Is there anything I can do to use just `mPosition` in the Derived class?

Comment: `mPosition` is a member of `Base<S>` which is a dependent type – read up on dependent types.

Comment: Unfortunately, no it really isn't possible, since you have a nondependent name in a dependent base class.

C++ does not look up nondependent names in dependent base classes. The answer is no.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming, the linked questions are Deerfield relevant and the phrasing "dependent type" was very helpful. Templates are still new and confusing to me...